# Find the number of Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, sylow-theory

Let $G=GL(2,\mathbb Z_p)$. Find a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$ and find the number of Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$.

**My try**:

$|G|=(p^2-1)(p^2-p)=p(p-1)^2(p+1)$. Hence any subgroup of order $p$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$. On taking $H=$ 
\begin{cases}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & x \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}:x\in \mathbb Z_p\end{cases}

$|H|=p$. Hence $H$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$.

Now the number of Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$ will be equal to the number of conjugates of $H$ in $G$.

But the problem is I can't proceed any more. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. You should consider the normalizer of $H$ now. Show that :

$$N_G(H)=\{\begin{pmatrix}\lambda&y\\0&\mu\end{pmatrix}\mid \lambda,\mu\in \left(\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{p\mathbb{Z}}\right)^*\text{ and } y\in \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{p\mathbb{Z}}\} $$

by strictly using linear algebra methods and conclude...

Comment: I will have to find the number of such subgroups..What to conclude from here? I did not get that.

Comment: @learnmore You should use the fact that the number of conjugate subgroups of $H$ is $|G|$ divided by $|N_G(H)|$.